# Configuring MySql inWildFly

Tags: mysql, jboss, wildfly

I followed the steps trying to configure MySQL in WildFly. I have two questions for your help with:

1) I downloaded the mysql-connector-java-5.1.33-bin.jar and placed it under modules/system/layers/base/com/mysql/main/. Do I need to download the actual MySql? Or the connector jar is sufficient?

2) In creating a new data source in WildFly console, I was not able to create a new data source. Part of the information I need to fill in is a pair of user name and password to access the database. Where should I create this user name and password first? I am guessing this is where I got the problem from.

I got this error message when testing the connection in wildfly console:

```
Unexpected HTTP response: 500

Request
{
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
        ("data-source" => "mysqlDSPool")
    ],
    "operation" => "test-connection-in-pool"
}

Response

Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "JBAS010440: failed to invoke operation: JBAS010447: Connection is not valid",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first you need to install Mysql server and a JDBC 4-compliant driver, normally all new JDBCs provided by  Mysql.org are JDBC 4-compliant, find a platform independant one [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/), then you need to add a datasource here in this file standalone/configuration/standalone.xml or using this command

```
data-source add --name=myDataSource--jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/myDataSource"                              \
            --connection-url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB"                                  \
            --driver-name=h2 --user-name="myDB_Username" --password="myPassword"
```

username and password are those used to connect to Mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to download the jdbc-driver jar which, I think, is the connector jar. But please don't place it under modules/system/... but directly under modules since the system folder is reserved for internal modules that are delivered with the server.

2) Here is an example (configures an Oracle datasource):

```
/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=OracleJdbcDriver:add(driver-module-name=oracle.jdbcaq,driver-name=OracleJdbcDriver)    

/subsystem=datasources/data-source=OracleDS:add(jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/OracleDS,enabled=true,jta=true,use-java-context=true,connection-url=jdbc:oracle:oci:@dbms:1523/DEV,driver-name=OracleJdbcDriver,min-pool-size=5,max-pool-size=100,user-name=username,password=password,prepared-statements-cache-size=100,exception-sorter-class-name=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter)
```

Comment: in addition to the connector jar, I think I also need to download MySql server and client and install it. Right? Otherwise, the connector alone won't work?

Comment: Yes of course you need to install the db server in order to work with it ;)